How to accurately aggregate CIELAB (or other color space) color values of multiple pixels?
Initial context
I am trying to aggregate color information from the pixels of an image, in this scenario and considering a Python environment, I have several .jpg images produced by the same camera with the same image size that I can read in any color space supported by Python (RGB, HSL, HSV, CIELAB, CMYK, ...). On each image there are certain segmentations marked by a binary mask. Once I have that color space and that binary mask I am trying to extract some short of "mean color" of the segmented object. Once I have that mean color for all the segmented objects of that image I am aggregating that info in a single color value. This might appear as a ridiculous question but there are certain points that need to be treated for the correct color info aggrupation that increased the complexity of this scenario:

In order to group something with a mean, + and - opperations need to have mathematical sense so that the same geometrical distance anywhere in the color space reflects the same amount of perceived color difference. For example, mean value in RGB always tends to generate a brownish color (like when you are painting and you mix lots of colors without any criteria and it ends up in some brownish nonsense color)

In order to group something with a median, you need the color space to follow certain logical ordering for the median value to be extracted. For example, in RGB you can't just simply go for the median value since you can't say whether an RGB value of [120, 100, 127] goes before or after [120, 111, 126].

Compression of jpg image format, as well as the camera sensor might alter the captured color of the image compared with the real color of the segmented object.


Image example
In the image below you can see an example of the rocks that I am analysing (background removed for visualization purposes) and the different Mean, Median and Mode RGB vales of all the pixels of interest. On the top-right corner there is a display of those RGB values. Traditionally in geology and mining, the color is relevant in order to determine the quality and properties of the material, for that purpose, the Munsell soil color book was used to assign a color (See How to Use a Munsell Soil Chart). In modern world with color digital cameras, RGB to Munsell color conversion is not straight-forward since you are missing color info to predict the hue, value, and chroma in the Munsell soil-color charts, there are some developments involving CNNs to predict Munsell color just from RGB images (See The Transformation of RGB Images to Munsell Soil-Color Charts). My point is that, there should be some short of color space aggregation technique that allows to mimic that Munsell soil-color "look up table" by analyzing .jpg images with Python. So in the end, having N pixels with N color values: How would you aggregate those color values in CIELAB in order to establish a human-perception-related color difference (CIELAB color difference) so that you can select the closest Munsell soil-color from the book's "look up table"?


Follow-up questions
Having that in mind, these are some related follow-up questions:

Considering that results should be consisten with human color perception, what is the best color space in order to make aggrupation operations with the information contained in each color channel? I guess it will make sense to go for uniform and device independent color spaces like CIELAB
Which mathematical operation will be adecuate to aggregate color information for the color space selected on the question 1? Mean, Median, Mode, ...
Is there any extra consideration that I might be missing?


Code samples
Some trials that I've been doing can be summarized in the following function:
def aggregate_rgb(binary_mask, image):

    # Change bgr to rgb
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Convert mask to boolean
    binary_mask = binary_mask.astype(bool)

    # Extract region inside the mask
    masked_image = rgb_image[binary_mask]

    # Calculate mode RGB values
    mode_rgb = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.uint8)
    # Reshape the masked image to a 2D array where each row represents a pixel and each column represents a channel
    reshaped_masked_image = masked_image.reshape(-1, 3)
    # Compute mode for each channel simultaneously
    channel_modes = mode(reshaped_masked_image, axis=0)

    # Calculate the custom RGB average
    num_pixels = np.sum(binary_mask)
    r = np.sum(masked_image[:, 0].astype('uint16') ** 2)
    g = np.sum(masked_image[:, 1].astype('uint16') ** 2)
    b = np.sum(masked_image[:, 2].astype('uint16') ** 2)


    # Calculate aggregate of RGB values
    mean_rgb = np.round(np.mean(masked_image, axis=0)).astype('uint8')
    median_rgb = np.round(np.median(masked_image, axis=0)).astype('uint8')
    mode_rgb = np.round(channel_modes.mode).astype('uint8')
    custom_mean_rgb = np.sqrt(np.array([r, g, b]) / num_pixels).astype('uint8')


    return mean_rgb, median_rgb, mode_rgb, custom_mean_rgb

The problem with those trials is mainly the selected color space (RGB) that tends to give brownish colors that are not very informative. I also managed to read the images in CIELAB color space by using this line cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab), but again I don't know if I should be doing means, medians and modes of the channels separately or if there is certain equation to follow considering that the L, A and B channels form geometrically a sphere.
I am using cv2 library for image display and color space readings and my Python version is 3.9.13 running on Visual Studio Code on Windows 10

References
I apologize beforehand for any mistake I might have made regarding the format of this question, if you feel like something else is needed I will be happy to add it. Thank you in advance!
Some interesting links that I checked before asking:

Computer Color is Broken by MinutePhysics 
Averaging colors the right way by Sighack
Color models in the mathematical and geometrical sense
Best color space for finding similar colors
Mean color for each superpixel in an image in the CIELAB color space


We can't see your images, or your expected results.

"my questions are the following" -- one question per question post, please.

all is lost if you aren't aware of the entire pipeline. one simple but impactful piece of the pipeline is gamma mapping. another is the spectrum of the light source. https://www.eecs.yorku.ca/~mbrown/ICCV19_Tutorial_MSBrown.pdf opencv seems unaware of color profiles embedded in images. it does not track color spaces. its color space conversions are usually linear, i.e. unlikely to respect any gamma mapping. if you want to get things "right", you'll either have to find a library that cares about this, or you'll have to implement it yourself. opencv is not for radiometry.

You need to average linear RGB. This is equivalent to mixing the light, and is what you would get if you put the object far away so that you see only one color. Averaging RGB doesn’t necessarily lead to brown. I’d say it usually doesn’t. But the average of disparate colors is likely to be near the gray axis of the RGB color space. You do get brown when you mix paints of many different colors. Averaging CIE Lab gives you a perceptual average, whatever that means. You can also average XYZ, which would be similar to the RGB result. Don’t average HSV or HSL or similar.

@ChristophRackwitz Wow, thanks a lot for that pdf, it was very informative. It looks like I might need to reconsider my pipeline after reading through it. Nevertheless, my goal is not to develop a code that makes physics-robust color interpretation I am sorry for the possible confussion regarding that. My goal with this is to find a color aggregation pipeline that is consistent with human perception of color. My main limitation is that I only have access to the .jpg images (Apparently incompatible with  CrisLuengo's linear RGB suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/50417764/21117172).

@MarkSetchell You're right. I'll add some images to clarify my pipeline

if you have a random JPG, you an always just assume a gamma of 2.4 or 2.22 or 1/0.45 or something like that, and "linearize" mostly correctly.

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks again for your comment. Would you mind on developing on that answer please? Could you explain the reasoning behind it? What do you mean by random JPG?

When discussing about perception, it is always difficult to agree on some definitions, so I would go to a more physical-world solution.
The ideal colour space is the colour model RGB (so RGB, XYZ, etc.). Note: the linear version (so no the common used sRGb, which it is gamma corrected).
If you keep floating point math, or just if you allow negative values and positive values above the normal limit of the colour space, it doesn't matter much which colour space (within such linear colour model) you choose, the result will be the same (after you convert back to the wanted destination colour space).
Such colour spaces describes well the physical light, so what your eye average (e.g. with a distance where you cannot resolve all pixels) is the same as a mathematical average. (Again: this is true only on linear spaces of RGB (or XYZ)).
I recommend to use XYZ (CIE XYZ) because often it is used as intermediate colour space, so you should have formula to convert from and to it.
